# How to add additional attributes to validator in jsr 303?

Tags: java, bean-validation

While writing my custom annotation and validator I faced with problem:

My code for annotation:

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = NumericValidator.class)
public @interface Numeric {

    String message() default "{constraint.postcode}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    int digitCount();
}
```

So that as you can see I need the addition parameter "digitCount". But this parameter is not mandatory so that I can use validation without, but according to this annotation I have to specify it anyway. I'd like to provide some default value for this parameter, and actually I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide a magic number for the default and ignore any annotation with the magic number. I used -1 as the magic number in this example:

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = NumericValidator.class)
public @interface Numeric {

    String message() default "{constraint.postcode}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    int digitCount() default -1;
}
```